# Streaming video encrypted by AES GCM in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, aes, hapi.js

I have some code that streams unencrypted video from S3, now I want to make it work for encrypted video files, for this purpose I use AES GCM.

However, html5 player fails to play it. I tried to decrypt the full file and it worked(without streaming). Any suggestions will be appreciated. 
The code is for HapisJS.

```
      const file = 'test/movie.mp4.enc';
      const s3Bucket = new S3();
      const paramsWholeFile = { Bucket: 'mybucket-v1', Key: file};
      const headWholeFile = await s3Bucket.headObject(paramsWholeFile).promise();
      const fileSize = headWholeFile.ContentLength!;

      const range = req.headers.range;
      console.log(range);

      const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
      let start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
      if (start > 0) {
        start -= (start % 16); // reading from the beginning of AES block
      }

      let end = parts[1]
        ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) - parseInt(parts[1], 10) % 16 # reading until the latest AES block
        : fileSize - 1;

      const chunksize = (end - start) + 1;
      //const file = Fs.createReadStream(path, {start, end})
      const params = { Bucket: 'mybucket-v1', Key: file, Range: `bytes=${start}-`};
      const object = s3Bucket.getObject(params);
      const stream = object.createReadStream();

      const dataKey = await CipherService.getDataKey(headWholeFile.Metadata!['x-amz-key']);
      const authTag = headWholeFile.Metadata!['x-amz-auth-tag'];

      const iv = new Buffer(headWholeFile.Metadata!['x-amz-iv'], 'base64');
      const decipher = Crypto.createDecipheriv(
        'aes-256-gcm',
        dataKey.Plaintext as Buffer,
        iv
      );
      decipher.setAuthTag(new Buffer(authTag , 'base64'));
      const decryptedStream = stream.pipe(decipher);

      const response = h.response(decryptedStream).code(206);
      response.header('Content-Range', `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`);
      response.header('Accept-Ranges', `bytes`);
      response.header('Content-Length', `${chunksize}`);
      response.header('Content-Type', `video/mp4`);
      return response;
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to decrypt and stream your video on the fly ? thanks !

Comment: How did it fail? What did you try to change and did the error change?

Comment: I think the reason could be in how you manage the byte range.